# Can a C variable be deleted or removed at any time during the running of a program?

Tags: c, free

I am wondering if it is possible to delete, that is remove from use, a C variable, say, for example, once the variable is used once?

I was reflecting some time ago on this subject, and one question arose in my mind.

C has many data types and we can create a variable of data type, say integer by the simple code

`int i;`

Once we have created a variable in this manner, how do we 'delete' it if we do not require it in future use?

I searched on the net, but did not find any C command that does this. By 'k is deleted', I mean 'k has ceased to exist'. I mean, once we do not need the variable, it is a waste, and should be removed.

C does provide the `free()` function, but it only works on memory allocated using `calloc(), malloc()`, or `realloc()`.

So how does one remove, say, an `int` variable, once it has been used?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't.  The object's lifetime ends once it goes out of scope (it is known as an *automatic* object, because it is automatically cleaned up).

e.g.

```
void foo() {
    int j = 3;

    while (blah) {
        int i = 5;
    }

    // i no longer exists
}

// j no longer exists
```

Comment: Thank you, but a what if a variable has been used up and is still in scope? Can one remove that?

Comment: @NihalPednekar: No.  But you should bear in mind that the compiler is very good at optimizing stack usage; most of your local variables will probably never exist in main memory anyway!

Comment: @NihalPednekar If you are desperately in need for ending the scope of a variable, you can just make your own custom block, using `{ ... }`, which behaves as any other sturctured block, ending the lifetime of any variable that was defined inside. But this is actually more of use in C++, where implicit destruction time sometimes matters. Oli is right in that the compiler is usually smart enough to see that a variable isn't used anymore and you shouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 5):

In C, there's the concept of *storage duration* of an object, which determines its lifetime:

- *static storage* lives for the entire execution of the program
- *thread storage* lives till thread termination
- *automatic storage* lives till the surrounding block is left
- *allocated storage* needs explicit de-allocation via `free()`

Allocated storage aside, the language runtime will take care of reclaiming memory (eg decreasing the stack pointer to discard call frames, which 'frees' automatic storage).

Comment: Thread storage didn't exist until C11, which is not widely adopted yet (AFAIK).

Comment: thread(-local) storage existed before C11 via language extensions, eg `__thread` in gcc and `__declspec(thread)` in MSVC